# SSDT build error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am getting the following exception during the build of my database projects.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(513,5): Error:  MSB4018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
14>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.ScriptCacheException: The cache identifier E:\Systems\MyProject\WorkingCopy-branch\source\Database.my_db_project\obj\debug.Deploy\ASMREXEXP.generated.sql does not exist.
```

The strange thing is that the build works fine on trunk, but fails with this exception on a feature branch.

Answer (score 10):

I just started to get this exact same error.  The fact that we're both seeing mention of `Schema.SchemaModel` suggests to me that we're both using some kind of text template strategy.

VS's build strategy for Text Template in the DB world requires that a `dbmdl` file has already been created in order for them to run.  This effectively means that you have to build the project twice; once  to build the new `dbmdl` file, then again to pick up the effects of haveing your text template dancing it.

What seems to happen - particularly when switching branches - is that you end up with an old `dbmdl` file that is *so* different from what the templates are expecting, that what the templates try to do is  odds with the "new" `dbmdl` file that the build is trying to create - it's like trying to cherry-pick a template patch based on the old `dbmdl` file and apply it to the new one - it doesn't work because the baselines are too far apart.

The solution is to find the `dbmdl` file in your source tree and delete it.  *Then* you can build to create a new `dbmdl` file.  the build will fail because the templates will fail, but you then build a *second* time and the template should pick up the new `dbmdl` file and succeed.

Comment: Rebuilding the dbmdl worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Still valid in VS 2022